# Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed

Tags: python, linux, numpy

I have installed the python package (numpy, scipy, matplotlib) using root through pip. These package are can work when i use root account. However, it raises import error when i using other accounts. Is there anyone met similar problem? how to solve it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tsKn.png)

Comment: ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: libmkl_rt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory